# Icon doesn't fit JButton with seaglass look-and-feel

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton, look-and-feel

I'm having trouble with a JButton.  I'm working with the [Seaglass Look-and-feel](http://code.google.com/p/seaglass/) and i want to add a Icon to my JButton. 
 But right now it doesn't fit, I have no idea what the problem could be. I use it on a JPanel that has a Flowlayout.

```
removeButton = new JButton();
        removeButton .setIcon(new ImageIcon("ICON/remove.png"));
        removeButton .setToolTipText("Remove");
        removeButton .setRolloverIcon(rolloverIcon2);
        removeButton .setBorderPainted(false);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JButton#setContentAreaFilled(false);](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setContentAreaFilled%28boolean%29), example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943584/update-jlabel-every-x-seconds-from-arraylistlist-java/7944388#7944388)