# GUI isn't shown while thread is in procces in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, concurrency

I'm making simple game with very simple thread (1 sec delay)
got problem with the thread, I have `while(true)` loop with the code:

```
try {
    while (true) {
       Ltimer.setText(getTimeElapsed());
       Thread.currentThread();
       Thread.sleep(1000); // Thread sleeping for 1 second           
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error with timer");       
}
```

it simply get string every second and  updates label text
when I'm trying to run it the gui freeze and I can only see the label in a black background, all buttons and bg img dissappeared. tried to fix with 
`setVisible()`
`repaint()`
but got nothing..

any other options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

don' use `Thread#sleep(int)` during EDT, then you have issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), if you need to delay any action use [java.swing.Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), example for [EDT lack here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943584/update-jlabel-every-x-seconds-from-arraylistlist-java/7944388#7944388)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you are using the GUI Event Thread to do this.  When you have the GUI thread tied up doing something else it cannot also be updating the screen.  I suggest you run a new thread to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You may not use Swing components outside of the event dispatch thread. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading

Use SwingUtilities.invokeLater each time your thread must change something in the UI. Or use a Swing [Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).

If this infinite loop is in fact in the EDT, then it blocks all the UI events, repaints, etc. while it's running. So you should run this loop in a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `SwingWorker`.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html