# JButton shows light blue background on Windows

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, look-and-feel

I have the following code to make a custom looking JButton

```
ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon(
                    CommonUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResource("images/wright.png")
                    );
            RightSlide.setIcon( icon );
            ImageIcon icon2 = createImageIcon(
                    CommonUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResource("images/right_selected.png")
                    );
            RightSlide.setPressedIcon( icon2);
            RightSlide.setSelectedIcon(icon2);
            RightSlide.setRolloverEnabled(true); // turn on before rollovers work
            RightSlide.setRolloverIcon(icon2);
            RightSlide.setBorderPainted(false);
            RightSlide.setFocusPainted(false);
            RightSlide.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
```

The code generates a custom button.  The button behaves as expected when hover over, pressed, clicked, and selected.  This works on MacOS and Linux (Ubuntu).  But the same code has a light blue background on Windows.  Where does this come from and how do I get rid of it ?

Thanks

Comment: its looks like LookandFeel issue.. check [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) with example there.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you missing [JButton#setContentAreaFilled(false);](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setContentAreaFilled%28boolean%29) example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943584/update-jlabel-every-x-seconds-from-arraylistlist-java/7944388#7944388)