# Java - Swing JLabel updates too quickly?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jlabel

In a method of a class, I update the same label twice. The first time, it shows the user message to wait, but the second time shows the user the completed message. Something like the following:

```
MyClass{

    myMethod(){

        jLabel.setText("Please wait...");

        //does calculation

        jLabel.setText("Completed successfully!");

        }
}
```

When I run the app, all I see is the "Completed successfully" message.  Is the JLabel updating too quickly? How do I control it? I tried using the following but no luck :(

```
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 jLabel.setText("Please wait...");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger, to step through your method and see what is happening? My initial guess is that your assumption is correct.

Comment: On a side note, never do (complex) calculations in the GUI thread - it'll cause the application to block (become unresponsive).  Generally, the 'proper' way to do this would be to cause an event that runs the calculation in its own thread.  Always use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to perform GUI updates/changes.

Answer (score 6):

If the calculation is done in the event dispatch thread, then it blocks the thread and prevents it from doing all its repaintings. You must do the computation in another thread, and have this thread change the label text when it ends (in the event dispatch thread, using SwingUtilities.invokeLater, or by using the SwingWorker mechanism). If the computation is really fast, it's not worth it, though, because the second text will appear so quickly after the first one that you won't even notice the first one.

Have a look at SwingWorker, which is designed for such use-cases. [Its javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) contains a useful example.

Comment: I did +1 but the only comment I have is that the 'other' thread shouldnt be setting the label, rather it should tell the EDT to set the label.  I am pretty sure that is what you mean, but it reads as if the other thread will invoke `label.setText(..)`

Answer (score 3):

if you want to delay some Action/Event then use [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), or wrap your code to the `Runnable#Thread`,

notice: never use `Thread.sleep(int)` durring EDT, your GUI freeze until `Thread.sleep(int)` ended

example for `javax.swing.Timer` & `Runnable#Thread` & `Freeze GUI` by implements `Thread.sleep(int)` durring EDT [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7944388/714968)

Answer (score -1):

Possibly because your calculations are happening too fast. Did you try putting a delay after your calc.

Also as Nizet points out above if this is happening in EDT the component will not repaint until end of the thread which means it will take the last set value.

Comment: -1 duplicate answer. Both points you tried to make have been made by other posters minutes earlier. You can add a comment to their answers if you wish.

Comment: I read it 3 times. You make a suggestion for the first point which was already made. You didn't even make a suggestion on how to solve the second point. So that should be added as a comment explaining the behaviour.