# JPanel freezes my whole application when trying to draw on it

Tags: java, swing, drawing, jpanel, freeze

I am coding Oregon Trail for a school project and I am implementing the hunting mini game. We are using model view presenter with a card layout. When the `HuntingPanel` gets switched to it calls run, and the `JOptionPane` comes up, but then the whole application freezes and I have to force quit. I coded the entire hunting game in a separate project, and just now brought the files over to the Oregon Trail game. It works fine in its own project with its own `JFrame`. I'm not sure what to do.

I call this to initialize the panel, switch to it, and run the game.

```
    public void initialize(int ammo) {
         player.setBullets(ammo);
         bulletLabel.setText("Bullets: "+player.getBullets());
         presenter.switchToPanel(OregonTrailPresenter.HUNTING_PANEL);
         run();
     }
```

This is my run method.

```
public void run() {
    // starting message
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have reached a nearby field to hunt. You will stay\nhere until " +
            "you run out of ammunition or click Return to Trail.");
    // while the player has bullets or doesn't click return to trail
    while (player.getBullets() > 0 && stillHunting) {
        // creates random animals
        checkForAnimal();
        // moves and updates screen
        repaint();
        update();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    endHunting();
}
```

And here are other method used.

```
private void checkForAnimal() {
    int x = 0;
    int y = rand.nextInt(MAX_Y)-40;
    int rand1 = rand.nextInt(100);
    String str = null;
    if (rand1 < 50) {
        str = "left";
        x = MAX_X-40;
    }
    else if (rand1 >= 50) {
        str = "right";
        x = 0;
    }

    double gen = rand.nextGaussian(); // gen is a number from -inf to +inf
    gen = Math.abs(gen); // gen is now a number from 0 to inf       
    if (gen >= 1.9 && gen < 2.1) { //1.19%
        animalList.add(new Bunny(x,y,str));
    }
    if(gen >= 2.1 && gen < 2.2) {  //0.9%
        animalList.add(new Bear(x,y,str));
    }
    if (gen >= 2.2 && gen < 2.3) { 
        animalList.add(new Deer(x,y,str));
    } 

}

    public void update() {
    for (int i = 0; i < animalList.size(); i++) {
        animalList.get(i).move();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to run your drawing stuff in a separate thread to avoid freezing your app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to implement [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of `Thread.sleep(int)`, because this code line freezes all GUI during [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) until `Thread.sleep(int)` ends. Here is [demonstrations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7944388/714968) what happens if the GUI is delayed during EDT by `Thread.sleep(int)`

Comment: +1 This will avoid creating a new thread which might introduce thread sync problems :)

Comment: @GETah: Just to clarify: [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) uses a single, shared thread; but the `actionPerformed()` runs on the EDT.

Comment: @trashgod Thanks. If I was in a similar situation, I would have a rendering thread to which I will submit rendering requests on `actionPerformed()` to avoid doing any CPU consuming operations in the EDT

Comment: @trashgod right and in this connection I strogly recomending don't, never to invoke SwingWorker from javax.swing.Timer,

Answer (score 2):

Your program "freezes" because you did not start a new thread for the while loop. Since the panel updates and redraws are handled in the main thread, you are preventing them from happening. To fix this problem you have to start a new thread. You can do this by making your class implement runnable and use new Thread(this).start() to run your loop.

```
class HuntingGame extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    public void initialize(int x) {
        //...
        new thread(this).start();// This will run your 'run()' method in a new thread.
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but don't forget to use [`invokeLater()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style#Continuations_as_objects) for GUI updates.