# Update Label text while button click action executing (Java)

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, event-dispatch-thread, settext

I have a button and Label on JFRAME.
Clicking on button try to connect linux Server and this takes few second.
I want to set the label text Connecting.. and Connected.But this doesn't set the label text Connecting .. during the button operation executing. Any Idea how to do that

```
private void buttonLConnectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    labelLOut.setText("Connecting");
    String ip="";
    String userid="username";
    String password="password";
Main_Window.LBoxconnect=new SshConnection(ip,userid,password);
    int x=LBoxconnect.checkConnection();
    if(x==1){
    labelLOut.setText("Connected");
    if(dx==1)
        buttonBTTInsert.setEnabled(true);
    else
        lx=1;
    }
    else
    labelLOut.setText("Connection Failed");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do long actions in a background thread, not in a button listener, otherwise your UI will seem frozen.

In your listener, set the text to "Connecting" and then launch a thread wrapping your connection stuff. At the end of the runnable, update the text again once the long operation has finished.

Comment: The answer here shows an example by using a swing worker: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916221/jlabel-will-not-update-unless-something-causes-the-method-to-hang

Comment: @Moh-Aw +1 nice link with explanations

Comment: Thanks,I'm trying to follow the suggested one.

Comment: Resolved the problem using SwingWorker, Thanks a lot!! Some more useful link on Swing Worker http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html  http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/