# drawImage() with using BufferedImage doesn't draw

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main
{
    JFrame jf;
    Main()
    {
        jf=new JFrame();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.add(new MyCanvas());
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyCanvas.img=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("1.jpg");
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Main();
            }
        });
    }
}
class MyCanvas extends JComponent
{
    static Image img;
    BufferedImage bi;
    MyCanvas()
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        bi=new BufferedImage(200,200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g=bi.getGraphics();
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
            for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
                g.drawImage(img,i*20,j*20,20,20,this);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(bi,0,0,this);
        //g.drawImage(img,0,0,this);
    }
}
```

If I uncomment line `g.drawImage(img,0,0,this);` I get my image on window. But with this code I see empty window. It is easy to understand that `g.drawImage(img,i*20,j*20,20,20,this);` in loop doesn't draw but what is problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edited out the unrelated stuff I did for future readers to find the answer easier.  In java i've always had to use getResource or getResourceAsStream to ensure the file loaded from the right directory correctly.

```
class MyCanvas extends JComponent
{
    public static Image loadImage(String s)
    {
        try 
        {
            return ImageIO.read(Main.class.getResource(s));
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `MyCanvas.img=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("1.jpg");` What is wrong in this line? With using `ImageIO.read()` I get desired result.

Comment: will you said `g.drawImage(img,0,0,this);` worked beforehand so that rules out the only thing I had to say which was that java is picky about what folder it considers root so it sometimes looks in the wrong place.

Comment: @eXXXXXXXXXXX: `createImage()` is asynchronous; +1 for `ImageIO`.

Answer (score 1):

1) put `BufferedImage` as [Icon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to the [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943584/update-jlabel-every-x-seconds-from-arraylistlist-java/7944388#7944388)

2) your `paintComponent` in CustomCanvas could be

```
class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return new Dimension(150, 150);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(bi,0,0,this);
    }
}
```