# not redisplaying an image s

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

Hi everybody  I am a bit of stack here. When I run the program and press the button submit it is supposed to change 4 pictures in every 2 seconds.However it is not redisplaying the images. If anyone can give me a hand it would be great. I am using eclipse and the program is compiling and running. Here is the code.

```
/** Here is the GUI of the program
 * class name SlideShowGui.java
 * @author Kiril Anastasov
 * @date 07/03/2012
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;   

public class SlideShowGui extends JPanel  implements ActionListener, Runnable
{
    JLabel name, comments, images;
    JTextField namejtf, commentsjtf, captionjtf;
    JButton submit;
    ImageIcon pictures1, pictures2, pictures3, pictures4;
    //ImageIcon []pictures2 = {galileo1.jpg};


    SlideShowGui()
    {


        name = new JLabel("Name:");
        this.add(name);

        namejtf = new JTextField(15);
        this.add(namejtf);

        comments = new JLabel("Comments:");
        this.add(comments);

        commentsjtf = new JTextField(15);
        this.add(commentsjtf);

        submit = new JButton("Submit");
        this.add(submit);
        submit.addActionListener(this);


        pictures1 = new ImageIcon("galileo1.jpg");
        images = new JLabel(pictures1);
        this.add(images);


        pictures2 = new ImageIcon("galileo2.jpg");
        this.add(images);
        pictures3 = new ImageIcon("galileo3.jpg");
        this.add(images);
        pictures4 = new ImageIcon("galileo4.jpg");
        this.add(images);



        captionjtf = new JTextField(24);
        this.add(captionjtf);
        //pictures = new ImageIcon("galileo1.jpg");
       // images.setIcon(pictures);  
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();

        if(ae.getSource() == submit)
        {

            int i = 0;
            boolean go = true;
            while(go)
            {

                i++;
                System.out.println(i);

                try 
                { 
                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                      if(i == 1)
                      {
                            pictures1 = new ImageIcon("galileo1.jpg");
                            images.setIcon(pictures1);                                                                                                      
                            System.out.println("picture 1 should be displayed here");
                      }
                      if(i == 2)
                      {
                            pictures2 = new ImageIcon("galileo2.jpg");
                            images.setIcon(pictures2);   
                            System.out.println("picture 2 should be displayed here");

                      }
                      if(i == 3)
                      {
                           pictures3 = new ImageIcon("galileo3.jpg");
                            images.setIcon(pictures3);   
                           System.out.println("picture 3 should be displayed here");  
                      }
                      if(i == 4)
                      {
                            pictures4 = new ImageIcon("galileo4.jpg");
                            images.setIcon(pictures4);   
                           System.out.println("picture 4 should be displayed here");  
                      }


                      if(i == 4)
                      {
                              i = 0;
                      }


                } 
                catch (InterruptedException ie) 
                {
                     System.out.println("thread exception");
                }

        }
    }

}

    public void run() 
    {

    }
}
```

---

```
/**The driver class of the program. Here is the JFrame 
 * class name TestSlideShow.java
 * @author Kiril Anastasov
 * @date 07/03/2012
 */

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TestSlideShow 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        SlideShowGui panel = new SlideShowGui();
        application.add(panel);
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.setSize(300,600);
        application.setLocation(400,100);
        application.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Comment: No No, you forgot again, yesterday the same question, was answered by @mKorbel, you forgot to apply even a single thing he said. Never use `Thread.sleep(...)` in Swing, that will freeze your app. Rather use `javax.swing.Timer` to achieve this behaviour. Where is your EDT?

Comment: @Gagandeep Bali stunt man :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always use `javax.swing.Timer` never use `Thread.sleep(...)` in Swing atleast. Here try this code, but do replace the `path` to your images :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SlideShow extends JPanel
{
    private int i = 0;
    private Timer timer;
    private JLabel images = new JLabel();
    private Icon bg = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon");
    private Icon red = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
    private Icon blue =  UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
    private ImageIcon pictures1, pictures2, pictures3, pictures4;
    private ActionListener action = new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {           

            boolean go = true;

            i++;
            System.out.println(i);

            if(i == 1)
            {
                images.setIcon(bg);                                                                                                      
                System.out.println("picture 1 should be displayed here");
            }
            if(i == 2)
            {
                images.setIcon(red);   
                System.out.println("picture 2 should be displayed here");
            }
            if(i == 3)
            {
                images.setIcon(blue);   
                System.out.println("picture 3 should be displayed here");  
            }
            if(i == 4)
            {
                images.setIcon(bg);   
                System.out.println("picture 4 should be displayed here");  
            }
            if(i == 5)
            {
                go = false;
                timer.stop();
                System.exit(0);
            }
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    };

    public SlideShow()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SLIDE SHOW");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);

        frame.getContentPane().add(this);

        add(images);

        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        timer = new Timer(2000, action);    
        timer.start();  
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new SlideShow();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kiril :  Hehe, Just remember -- Keep Smiling :-)

Comment: @mKorbel : Thankyou and Keep Smiling :-)

Answer (score 4):

The whole `if (i == ...` part can be simplified. Declare a static class member in `SlideShowGUI`:

```
private final static ImageIcon[] icons = {new ImageIcon("galileo1.jpg"),
                                          new ImageIcon("galileo2.jpg"),
                                          new ImageIcon("galileo3.jpg"),
                                          new ImageIcon("galileo4.jpg")};
```

and use it in the replacement of the `if` statements:

```
images.setIcon(icons[i-1]);
System.printf("Picture %s should be displayed%n", i-1);
if (i == 4) {
  i = 0;
}
```

Comment: (my answer was a general hint and it should not solve the actual problem with redisplaying images...)

Comment: this is [one of reason why Queue is there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7944388/714968) +1 for basic stuff

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify your code as Andreas_D mentioned.

Your current design will block the main thread as you call `Thread.sleep()` to it, this will freeze your application.

If you would like to update the `Image`, you should implement the update code inside `run()` method.

So if you detect the user press on submit `JButton`, create and start the new `Thread` for updating UI.