# draw image in applet

Tags: java, image, swing, paint, japplet

i having problem with draw image in applet. i want to display all images one by one in applet but it shows only last image of the folder my code is given below.

```
public class ImageInSwingTest extends JApplet
{
    String filePath="C:\\Users\\yogi\\Pictures\\pictures"; //all .png files more than 200 files
    String files;
    File folder=new File(filePath);
    File[] listOfFiles;
    Image m;

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        listOfFiles=folder.listFiles();
        for(int i=0;i<listOfFiles.length;i++)
        {
            if(listOfFiles[i].isFile())
            {
                files=listOfFiles[i].getName();
                if(files.endsWith(".png"))
                {
                    String filepath=listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();
                    System.out.println(filepath);
                    try {
                         m = ImageIO.read(new File(filepath));
                        paint(ImageInSwingTest.this.getGraphics());

                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ImageInSwingTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(m, 0, 0, this);

    }

}
```

so, please can any one tell me how can i display all images one by one.?
Thanks.

Comment: `String filePath="C:\\Users\\yogi\\Pictures\\pictures";`  This will not work for your images on the server, even in a trusted applet.  It will be necessary for either the server to supply a file list on demand, or for the file names to be defined as parameters in the applet element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so, please can any one tell me how can i display all images one by one.? Thanks.

- because each of loop inside `for(int i=0;i<listOfFiles.length;i++)` replacing `JApplet`'s contents
- put `JPanel` to the `JApplet`
- put `Images` to the array of `Icon[]`
- put `Icon` to the `JLabel`
- use `GridLayout` for placing `JLabel` with `Icons` to the `JPanel`
- don't paint to the `JApplet` directly, use `JPanel` or `JComponent` with override method `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()`

EDIT

> actually i want all images to replace each other so all images are look like playing movie

- you have to pause this process by `Thread.sleep(int);`
- you can use `Thread.sleep(int);` inside `SwingWorker` or `Runnable#Thread`,
- don't use `Thread.sleep(int);` other ways in the Swing GUI, because to block Event Dispatch Thread, and is possible that nothing will be painted or only the last image too
- `Runnable#Thread` would be better and easiest, but any output from `Runnable#Thread` to the Swing GUI you have to wrap `JLabel.setIcon(myIcon)` to the `invokeLater`

Comment: actually i want all images to replace each other so all images are look like playing movie.

Comment: Also consider using a [*Swing Timer*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: @yogeshpatel : Have a look at this example of [Slide Show](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630724/not-redisplaying-an-image-s/9631116#9631116)

Answer (score 0):

The time taken to end the loop is so short you can only see the last image displayed. Try adding a `pause` after drawing each image.