# I'm reading the Head First Java,but I feel puzzled about this program

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class twobuttons
{
    int x=70;
    int y=70;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        twobuttons gui =new twobuttons();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        mydraw drawpanel = new mydraw();

        frame.getContentPane().add(drawpanel);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for(int i=0;i<130;i++)
        {
            x++;
            y++;

            drawpanel.repaint();
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

    }
    class mydraw extends JPanel
    {

        public void paintconponent(Graphics g)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);
        }
    }
}
```

this is a code from the Head First Java,chapter 12,p384(I am reading the Chinese edition ,maybe it's not in the same page in the English edition.)If successful,there should be a dot running from the left corner to the right corner,however,I can't see anything in the window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo in the painting class (paintconponent => paintComponent). So you were not overriding the behavior of the JComponent super class. Try this:

```
class mydraw extends JPanel
{

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to admit that the laziness and carelessness kill me!

Answer (score 4):

If this snippet is literally copy-pasted from the book, I would throw the book away

- Swing operations should happen on the EDT, so the `main` method needs an `EventQueue.invokeLater` (or similar)
- Calling `Thread.sleep` on the same `Thread` where the painting is performed will not work.

StackOverflow is filled with questions why `Thread.sleep` does not work on the EDT, and possible work-arounds. In this case, I would use a Swing `Timer` to move the dot and trigger the repaint

Comment: The real book is well-regarded and the [real example](http://books.google.com/books?id=5VTBuvfZDyoC&pg=PA379&lpg=PA379&dq=Head+First+Java+two+buttons+code&source=bl&ots=aplyIGdRvS&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fj1iT8uYNOja0QGgt43LCA&sqi=2&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=Head%20First%20Java%20two%20buttons%20code&f=false) looks better.

Comment: @trashgod That looks better indeed. Never read the book myself so my comments was only based on the snippet posted in the question

Answer (score 2):

1) never use Thread.sleep(int) during EDT, this code line caused flickering or freeze of Swing GUI, example about freeze [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7944388/714968)

2) Swing GUI should be started in [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

3) use [Swing Time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)r for animations or pausing of Swing GUI

4) learn [Java Naming Convention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)