# How to add image in the panel?

Tags: java, image, swing, applet

I want to add an image in the panel together with the description but the description appear only in the list whenever I choose a year in my combobox, the problem is that the image didn't show in the lower part of the panel. I guess somethings wrong with my code. Could someone help me about this?

This is what I've tried so far :

```
public class Main extends JApplet
{
private String[] description;
private JList list = new JList();
private DefaultListModel defaultListModel = new DefaultListModel();
private JComboBox c = new JComboBox();
private JButton b = new JButton("Ok");
private ImageIcon image;

public void init()
{
    try
    {
        description = new String[22];
        description[0] = "1990";
        description[1] = "1991";
        description[2] = "1992";
        description[3] = "1993";
        description[4] = "1994";
        description[5] = "1995";
        description[6] = "1996";
        description[7] = "1997";
        description[8] = "1998";
        description[9] = "1999";
        description[10] = "2000";
        description[11] = "2001";
        description[12] = "2002";
        description[13] = "2003";
        description[14] = "2004";
        description[15] = "2005";
        description[16] = "2006";
        description[17] = "2007";
        description[18] = "2008";
        description[19] = "2009";
        description[20] = "2010";
        description[21] = "2011";
        description[22] = "2012";
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    c = new JComboBox(description);
    list = new JList(defaultListModel);

    list.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
    b.setText("<html><b><u>Click</click></b></html>");
    list.setFont(new Font("Garamond", Font.BOLD, 17));
    list.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

    JLabel label = new JLabel(image);

    JPanel down = new JPanel();
    down.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100, 100, 100, 100));
    down.add(label);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.add(c);
    panel.add(b);

    Container cp = getContentPane();

    cp.add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    cp.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    cp.add(down, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    this.setVisible(true);

    b.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent
                                                    event)
                {
                    int select;
                    select = c.getSelectedIndex();
                    defaultListModel.clear();
                    if (select == 0)
                    {
                        defaultListModel.addElement("the year of 1990");

                        image = new ImageIcon("chicken.gif");
                    }
              }
            });
}
```

Comment: How are you running the code?  Are you checking the Java console?  Why code an applet rather than a frame?  I can probably guess why it is failing, but this will be more instructive for you.  BTW - replace the `String[]` with a [`DefaultComboBoxModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html) and loop to `addElement()` 22 times.

Comment: In your `ActionListener` try to use `label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("chicken.gif"))` I'm not sure that create a new Image is enough. (the label should be declare in the class not in init() if you do that)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have a mistake at the beginning of `init()` method, which is not related with your actual question. You have an array of 22 strings and you are trying to assign a value to 23rd index, that's wrong, you will get an error unless you abandon it.

For your actual question, changing the value of an image doesn't change/update the label. Try the code snippet below in `actionPerformed()` method, however you need to make your label a final or a global variable.

```
if (select == 0)
{
    try
    {
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("chicken.gif"))));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, it appears now but the problem is too big. how can I adjust it? Do i need to make the paint method?

Comment: no you can use a file array to set to imageicons, and wrap up all if-else clauses into a single try-catch.

Comment: I mean is that the image is too big

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things you are doing wrong in your code.

1. The size of the `String Array` description is 22, and you are adding a value to the index 22, this will lead to `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
2. The ImageIcon created by you has nothing it's null, so when you add it to `JLabel`, it will be showing nothing, as expected.
3. A BorderLayout object has five areas. These areas are specified by the BorderLayout constants: Namely `PAGE_START`, `PAGE_END`, `LINE_START`, `LINE_END` and `CENTER`. But you are using NORTH, EAST, WEST, SOUTH approach, this is old.

Here I had Modified your code a bit, have a look, is your image coming or not now.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JApplet
{
    private String[] description;

    private JList list = new JList();

    private DefaultListModel defaultListModel = new DefaultListModel();

    private JComboBox c = new JComboBox();

    private JButton b = new JButton("Ok");

    private ImageIcon image;

    private Icon infoIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");


    public void init()
    {


        try
        {


            description = new String[22];

            description[0] = "1990";
            description[1] = "1991";
            description[2] = "1992";
            description[3] = "1993";
            description[4] = "1994";
            description[5] = "1995";
            description[6] = "1996";
            description[7] = "1997";
            description[8] = "1998";
            description[9] = "1999";
            description[10] = "2000";
            description[11] = "2001";
            description[12] = "2002";
            description[13] = "2003";
            description[14] = "2004";
            description[15] = "2005";
            description[16] = "2006";
            description[17] = "2007";
            description[18] = "2008";
            description[19] = "2009";
            description[20] = "2010";
            description[21] = "2011";
            //description[22] = "2012";
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        c = new JComboBox(description);
        list = new JList(defaultListModel);

        list.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
        b.setText("<html><b><u>Click</click></b></html>");
        list.setFont(new Font("Garamond", Font.BOLD, 17));
        list.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

        final JLabel label = new JLabel(image);


        JPanel down = new JPanel();
        down.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100, 100, 100, 100));
        down.add(label);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.add(c);
        panel.add(b);

        Container cp = getContentPane();

        cp.add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cp.add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        cp.add(down, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        this.setVisible(true);


        b.addActionListener(

            new ActionListener()
            {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent
                                                    event)
                {
                    int select;
                    select = c.getSelectedIndex();
                    defaultListModel.clear();
                    if (select == 0)
                    {
                        defaultListModel.addElement("the year of 1990");

                        label.setIcon(infoIcon);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        label.setIcon(null);
                    }
              }
            });
    }
}
```

A better approach to access an Image using `ImageIO` with `URL`, since image is an `Application Resource`, so it's much wiser to access it via a `URL` instead of a `File` is shown in this post of mine : [Access Images via ImageIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721421/show-image-by-click-jbutton/9722205#9722205)

Answer (score 2):

I use this to resize my ImageIcon :

```
               if (select == 0)
                {
                    defaultListModel.addElement("the year of 1990");
                    image = new ImageIcon("chicken.gif") 
                    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getScaledImage(image.getImage(), 32, 32))))
                }
  ....

    /**
     * Resizes an image using a Graphics2D object backed by a BufferedImage.
     * @param srcImg - source image to scale
     * @param w - desired width
     * @param h - desired height
     * @return - the new resized image
     */
    private Image getScaledImage(Image srcImg, int w, int h){
        BufferedImage resizedImg = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics2D g2 = resizedImg.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2.drawImage(srcImg, 0, 0, w, h, null);
        g2.dispose();
        return resizedImg;
    }
```