# 2nd image display over the first image

Tags: java, image, swing

i want to display an image the first time i  execute it it works fine but when it is again executed then it show the previous image not the latest one!!!..
i know this might be because of the new image is being added below the first.

```
package drivers;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main implements ActionListener
{
    private JFrame f;
    private JLabel lb_name,lb_email,lb_address,lb_hourlyrate,lb_startdate,lb_enddate,lb_reason,lb_homeph,lb_cellph,lb_image;
    private JTextField tx_name,tx_email,tx_address,tx_hourlyrate,tx_startdate,tx_enddate,tx_homeph,tx_cellph;
    private JButton bt_go,bt_next,bt_image;
    private JTextArea txf_reason;
    private ImageIcon ic;
    private JPanel p;

    public String s="d:\\3.jpg";

    public Main()
    {
        f=new JFrame();
        lb_name=new JLabel("Name");
        lb_email=new JLabel("E-mail");
        lb_address=new JLabel("Address");
        lb_hourlyrate=new JLabel("Hourly Rate");
        lb_startdate=new JLabel("Starting Date");
        lb_enddate=new JLabel("Enddate");
        lb_reason=new JLabel("Reason of Quiting");
        lb_homeph=new JLabel("Home Phone");
        lb_cellph=new JLabel("Cell Phone");
        tx_name=new JTextField();
        tx_email=new JTextField();
        tx_address=new JTextField();
        tx_hourlyrate=new JTextField();
        tx_startdate=new JTextField();
        tx_enddate=new JTextField();
        txf_reason=new JTextArea();
        tx_homeph=new JTextField();
        tx_cellph=new JTextField();
        bt_image=new JButton("Browse");
        bt_image.addActionListener(this);
        bt_go=new JButton("Go");
        bt_go.addActionListener(this);
        bt_next=new JButton("Next");
        bt_next.addActionListener(this);
        ic =new ImageIcon(s);
        lb_image=new JLabel(ic);
        p=new JPanel();
        p.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(255,255,255), 1, true));
    }

    public void launch()
    {

        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setSize(630,470);
        f.add(lb_name);
        f.add(lb_email);
        f.add(lb_address);
        f.add(lb_hourlyrate);
        f.add(lb_startdate);
        f.add(lb_enddate);
        f.add(lb_reason);
        f.add(lb_homeph);
        f.add(lb_cellph);
        f.add(tx_name);
        f.add(tx_email);
        f.add(tx_address);
        f.add(tx_hourlyrate);
        f.add(tx_startdate);
        f.add(tx_enddate);
        f.add(txf_reason);
        f.add(tx_homeph);
        f.add(tx_cellph);
        f.add(bt_go);
        f.add(bt_next);
        f.add(p);
        p.add(lb_image);
        lb_image.setBounds(0,0,200,200);
        p.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        lb_name.setBounds(20,30,50,30);
        tx_name.setBounds(60,30,150,30);
        bt_go.setBounds(270,30,60,30);
        lb_email.setBounds(20,110,40,30);
        tx_email.setBounds(130,113,200,25);
        lb_address.setBounds(20,140,50,30);
        tx_address.setBounds(130,143,200,25);
        lb_hourlyrate.setBounds(20,170,70,30);
        tx_hourlyrate.setBounds(130,173,60,25);
        lb_startdate.setBounds(20,200,80,30);
        tx_startdate.setBounds(130,203,150,25);
        lb_enddate.setBounds(20,230,80,30);
        tx_enddate.setBounds(130,233,150,25);
        lb_homeph.setBounds(20,260,80,30);
        tx_homeph.setBounds(130,263,100,25);
        lb_cellph.setBounds(20,290,80,30);
        tx_cellph.setBounds(130,293,100,25);
        lb_reason.setBounds(20,320,100,30);
        txf_reason.setBounds(130,323,200,70);
        bt_next.setBounds(400,380,60,40);
        p.setBounds(350,100,220,240);
        tx_email.setEditable(false);
        tx_address.setEditable(false);
        tx_hourlyrate.setEditable(false);
        tx_startdate.setEditable(false);
        tx_enddate.setEditable(false);
        tx_homeph.setEditable(false);
        tx_cellph.setEditable(false);
        txf_reason.setEditable(false);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      Main m=new Main();
      m.launch();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource().equals(bt_go))
        {
            try
            {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:project","sa","123456");
                String s=tx_name.getText();
                Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT name,address,email,startdate,enddate,reason,homeph,cellph,hourlyrate,image FROM driver");
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    if(s.equals(rs.getString(1)))
                    {
                        tx_address.setText(rs.getString(2));
                        tx_email.setText(rs.getString(3));
                        tx_startdate.setText(rs.getString(4));
                        tx_enddate.setText(rs.getString(5));
                        txf_reason.setText(rs.getString(6));
                        tx_homeph.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(7)));
                        tx_cellph.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(8)));
                        tx_hourlyrate.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(9)));
                        s=rs.getString(10);
                        ic=new ImageIcon(s);
                        lb_image=new JLabel(ic);
                        f.add(lb_image);
                        lb_image.setBounds(350,100,200,200);
                        bt_go.setEnabled(false);
                        tx_name.setEditable(false);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(f,ex);
            }
        }
        else if(e.getSource().equals(bt_next))
        {
            enter en=new enter();
            en.launch();
            f.hide();
        }
        else if(e.getSource().equals(bt_image))
        {
            String s;
            JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
            jfc.showDialog(jfc, "Choose an image file");
            s = jfc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            imagePath.setText(s);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of adding a new `JLabel` for updating an image, simply use `JLabel.setIcon(newImage)` For example : [Updating an image contained in a JLabel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10051684/1057230). Stop using `Absolute Positiong` instead use some `Layout Manager`.

Comment: Another related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15187181/1057230)

Comment: And please in future, do read these documents before posting a question, [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) by __Andrew Thompson__, [The Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) by __Jon Skeet__, [Smart Questions](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) by __Eric Steven Raymond__ and [Why should I downvote](http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvote.html) by __Emil Vikstrom__