# java set delay to change imageicon

Tags: java, swing, delay, mouselistener, thread-sleep

i'm trying to set a delay when a button is pressed to set an imageicon to a certain image then set another delay so that another image would be set, all of this by single click.
in other word :

click a button->set image->delay->set another image.

what i get in my code is the last state only "set another image".

also i don't want to use use timers, i want to use delays.

and here the part in my code i'm concerned about.

```
btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    lblNewLabel.setIcon(and);   
sleeep(500);
        lblNewLabel.setIcon(app);
    }
});
```

and here is the delay function

```
 void sleeep(int n)
{
    try {
        Thread.sleep(n);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051638/updating-an-image-contained-in-a-jlabel-problems

Comment: @tokhi didn't i mention that i don't want to use timers.

Answer (score 1):

1. don't add [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) to [`JButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), nor for `mouseClicked()`, add [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) instead, btw all `Mouse` and `Key` events are implemented in [`JButton API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) and correctly
2. don't to use `Thread.sleep(n);` you have an issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), use [`Swing Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead,

Comment: adding action listener gave the same result plus i mentioned i didn't want to use timers.

Comment: then result never will be stable

Comment: i intend to freeze the whole program while the images are changed, that's why i don't want to use timers....i know i can set objects unclickable while the timer is working but using a delay would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should try executing the code that sets the image in the event dispatch thread using InvokeLater.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        lblNewLabel.setIcon(and);
    }
});

sleeep();

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        lblNewLabel.setIcon(and);
    }
});
```

Comment: It won't work reliably, as long as you don't do the `sleep` on another thread, and *then* schedule the `invokeLater` to set the last icon.