# Java Swing Icon not appearing

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a piece of code that displays either a smiley face or a sad face when a button is pressed, depending on some value, but it just won't display the image. I know that it's definitely getting past the if/else statements, so I really don't know what is going wrong.

```
 try {
    if(data[2] <= ((int) ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(localDate, RTS()))*MnHrs())
    {
        JLabel lblSmiley = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\. . .\\smileyface.jpeg"));
        panel.add(lblSmiley);
    }
    else
    {
        JLabel lblSmiley = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\ . . . \\sadeface.png));
        panel.add(lblSmiley);
    }
} catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: revalidate/repaint panel.

Comment: I tried using "panel.repaint()" and "panel.revalidate()" but it didn't work

Comment: revailidate then repaint

Comment: Still not working

Comment: This will help     https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Antoniossss Great suggestion re posting an MCVE, and a tip. `[mcve]` in a comment will auto-expand to [mcve]. OP: One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: I tried both combinations of "panel.repaint()" and "panel.revalidate()" within the if/else statements and it produced no changes.

Comment: @AndrewThompson to be honest, sometimes it expands for me, sometimes id dont (after just pasting link)

Comment: @Antoniossss *"sometimes it expands for me, sometimes id don't"* There must be differences in how it is posted (e.g. no space before /after the 6 letters). I've posted it ..I was about to say hundreds, but it'd easily be thousands of times now, and it has worked every single time.

Comment: @R.McGuigan: Can't you just at the label once and use `setIcon()`?

Comment: @CatalinaIsland I swear I did that before, but now it seems to be working, thanks!

Comment: @R.McGuigan: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're loading the icon and adding a new label each time. Instead, you can add the label once and call `setIcon()` like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10051684/261156).

```
Icon smile = new ImageIcon("C:\\…\\smileyface.jpeg");
Icon sad = new ImageIcon("C:\\…\\sadeface.png");
JLabel lblSmiley = new JLabel();
…
frame.add(lblSmiley);
…
if (…) {
    lblSmiley.setIcon(smile);
} else {
    lblSmiley.setIcon(sad);
}
```

Depending on your layout, you may need to change the labels preferred size or add an empty label before you `pack()` the window.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it is getting in the panel, but due to dimensions of panel it might be getting placed off screen. Check by modifying the panel dimensions and placing the smiley within that.

Comment: *"modifying the panel dimensions"* The correct way to do that is to `pack()` the top level container. The programmer should not be trying to guess the size needed (for a cross-platform GUI that is designed using layouts).