# Loading animated GIF in JLabel weirdness

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, animated-gif

I'm trying to load an animated GIF in a JLabel.

While this works:

```
URL urlsd;
try {
    urlsd = new URL("http://pscode.org/media/starzoom-thumb.gif");
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(urlsd); 
    JLabel progress = new JLabel(imageIcon);    
    progress.setBounds(5, 20, 66, 66);
    contentPane.add(progress);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This, on the other hand, does not, and I don't want to get the GIF from an URL, since I already have the GIF. Result of loading this shows only the first frame of the GIF:

```
try {   
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("res/images/progress_indicator.gif")));

    JLabel progress = new JLabel(imageIcon);
    imageIcon.setImageObserver(progress);
    progress.setBounds(5, 20, 66, 66);
    contentPane.add(progress);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I guess there must be a reason for this, but I cannot find it.

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: ClassLoader is really not the way to access, `Application Resources`, try this link, hope this might be of some help, [HOW TO LOAD IMAGES INTO YOUR PROJECT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/load-icon-image-exception/9866659#9866659)

Comment: Why not ClassLoader, as described in this [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html), which states that "All class loaders will search for a resource first as a system resource, in a manner analogous to searcing for class files"

Comment: @AlejandroVK : For a working example consult this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721421/show-image-by-click-jbutton/9722205#9722205)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try loading your GIF file like that:

```
public class Test extends JPanel {
    public Test() {
        ImageIcon imageIcon =
          new ImageIcon(Test.this.getClass().getResource("starzoom-thumb.gif"));
    }
}
```

Or using `Test.class.getResouce()` if your context is static.

Comment: Ahha, I will go with this answer, `getClass().getResource(...)` is the way to go :-)

Comment: I suspect this is the answer.  Strange things happen with the streams returned by `getResourceAsStream` (e.g. sound apps. might fail because the stream is 'not repositionable').  But provide an `URL` and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, altough I had to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960381/runnable-jars-missing-buttons/9278270#9278270 in order to realize that I had to include a slash first...something not required using the getSystemResourceAsStream approach :D

Comment: Note that if your GIF is at `myProject/src/main/resources/icons/myGif.gif` you should pass `"icons/myGif.gif` to `getResource`. This contrasts with the usage of `getResourceAsStream` where you have to prepend a slash to your file path: `"/icons/myGif.gif`.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me, it will show the animation instead of first frame of the image.

```
public class Test extends JPanel {
    public Test() {
        ImageIcon yyyyIcon = new ImageIcon(xxx.class.getClassLoader().getResource("yyyy.gif"));
        connectionLabel.setIcon(yyyy);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

So there is also a simpler way of doing it. The following line is how I did it.

```
this.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Path To Gif File")));
```