# JLabel not showing .gif animation

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, gif, bufferedimage

I am trying to put a ".gif" image on a label. The image loads , but it is static (no animation). Any guesses why? and how to solve it?

Code that I am using:

```
BufferedImage img1=ImageIO.read(TCPServer.class.getResource("filecopy.gif"));
JLabel filetransferpic = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img1));
```

Note: I don't want to use..

```
JLabel filetransferpic = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("G:\\filecopy.gif"));
```

..approach. Because in this approach I will have to give drive path and place the image in drive. I want the image in project folder "src".

Comment: Another question that may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622303/loading-animated-gif-in-jlabel-weirdness

Comment: See also [Show an animated BG in Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836832/show-an-animated-bg-in-swing).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example, you are using a `BufferedImage`. Instead, use an `ImageIcon`, like this:

```
ImageIcon gifImage = new ImageIcon(new URL("file:/Path/To/file.gif"));
JLabel yourLabel = new JLabel(gifImage);
```

This should be animated. But remember, the constructor URL(String) throws a `MalformedURLException`; make sure to catch it.