# Make label with any image (gif and other)

Tags: java, image, gif, imageicon

What I want to do is:

- Load an image that it is a gif, jpeg etc ... coming from a URL (but it is only the gif that I do not arrive but it must work with the others)
- Put it in a JLabel in IconImage (although it suits me if it is not in the icon of the label as long as it is in the label)
- Make it auto resize by taking all the space of the label but keeping its ratio
- And finaly make this.add (label)

I already managed to do it with any type of image but the gifs was freeze to the first image

I searched for more solutions but could not find any that worked for me.

So, if someone could help me from the very beginning. I have the URLs and can share, if required.

Exemple of my code

//that work but images is not resize

`JLabel label = new JLabel(); 
 label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL(image.getPath()))); 
 this.add(label);`

//images don't appear

`URL url = new URL(image.getPath()); 
JLabel label = new JLabel(); 
java.awt.Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url); 
img = this.scaleImage(img,Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width/6); label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));`

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622303/loading-animated-gif-in-jlabel-weirdness

Comment: //that work but images is not resize
`
`JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL(image.getPath())));
    this.add(label);`
    
   
//images don't appear<br/>
    `URL url = new URL(image.getPath());
          JLabel label = new JLabel();
          java.awt.Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);
          img = this.scaleImage(img, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width/6);
    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
    this.add(label);`

@Rob

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you may need to put it in a try-catch

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(url));
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
```

Comment: @RSDing
I get an error



javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1395)

Comment: Which URL are you using

Comment: Ah no I just relaunched it to work ... short the problem is that the gifs and other "video" format are freeze on the first frame and moreover it returns a null if the format is a .webm