# How to investigate SwingWorker start delay?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, debugging, swingworker

Consider the following simple method which is part of an appication with Swing gui:

```
public void updateFromGoogle(int action)  {

    startTime =  System.currentTimeMillis();

    model.updateFromGoogle(action);

    System.out.println("Total run time "
    + (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));

}
```

Run time i=of the above method is consistently under 1 milli.

If I add to the method a `SwingWorker` that does nothing:

```
public void updateFromGoogle(int action)  {


    startTime =  System.currentTimeMillis();

    SwingWorker sw = new SwingWorker<Boolean, Void>(){

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Swing worker start after "
                    + (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void done() {

            System.out.println("Swing worker finished after "
                    + (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));
        }

    };

    sw.execute();

    model.updateFromGoogle(action);

    System.out.println("Total run time "
    + (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));

}
```

**Occasionally** I can see that the `SwingWorker` **starts** after a very long time, for example (millis):

> Swing worker start after 19734
>
> Swing worker finished after 19767

Questions: 

1. Does it suggest that some other long task is Occasionally running on the Event Dispatch Thread ? 

2.How do I investigate which task is causing it ?

**Edit:** Following comment I installed `jvisualvm` that shows that `SwingWorker` uses a pool of 8 threads :

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Busy loop in other thread delays EDT processing*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35154352/230513); see update 6.

Comment: I don't think it answers my question (it doesn't even answer the question posted there)

Comment: I didn't think so either; the bug report proved dispositive.

Comment: @c0der probably your SwingWorker uses a single thread and this thread is busy by another background task?

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy yes, I think this is expressed in question 1. I wonder how I verify it, and how to I investigate which other long process run on EDT.

Comment: Have a look at the stack traces, either using a Debugger or by a separate background Thread which prints the trace for [every thread](http://javadoc.imagej.net/Java8/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces--).

Comment: @c0der try to use `jvisualvm` utility, which is a part of JDK or another profiler. So you can see the number of threads. Swing worker threads have prefix `SwingWorker-`. If you have only 1 thread - it could be your problem

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Thanks. I will look up `jvisualvm` utility. (I thought that Swing should be single thread ?)

Comment: [to check code from my two answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6171414/714968), I'm doubt in fack that Future is single threaded, there is delay in miliseconds, not in seconds, something went wrong with code inside your real code, maybe another code executions are without mentioned delay

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy following your comment I installed `jvisualvm` and I can see that `SwingWorker` uses a pool of 8 threads. I still do not know how to get more useful information out of the profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Following @SergiyMedvynskyy comment I installed `jvisualvm`. 

By sampling cpu I found that another `SwingWorker` process is running for a long time, apparently blocking others :

[image]