# Painting over a custom JPanel with background paints at arbitrary positions in java

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I am using a custom `JPanel` with a background image. I have put the background image by overriding the panel's `paintComponent()` method. The layout of the panel is set to `GridBagLayout`. Now I am trying to add another JPanel to it on which I am drawing a rectangle.

When I am trying to do that the rectangle is drawn at arbitrary positions and its duplicates are also being drawn. When I remove the background image of the first panel everything works fine.

How to solve this?

Comment: no ideas, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrated a.m. issue, with [hardcoded BufferedImage](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7944388/714968)

Comment: "If you do not honor the [opaque](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#props) property (by calling `calling super.paintComponent()`) you will likely see visual artifacts."—`JComponent`

Comment: I am calling super.paintComponent() but  the problem continues