# JLabel Icon resisting change

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I have an icon for a JLabel which I can see the change for only once. When blank, a new set image for the below code works as it should. But after that, the image is stuck. No new image can replace it. When I use repaint on panelPainting without revalidate(), I get no pictures at all. Thats also weird.

Here is the code, (panelMain houses panelPainting)

```
//get image from somewhere
JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
Icon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
imageLabel.setIcon(imageIcon);

panelPainting.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER);
panelPainting.add(imageLabel);  // default center section

//my insanity starts here
panelPainting.revalidate();

panelMain.remove(panelPainting);
panelMain.revalidate();
```

EDIT: I double checked that the **image** does change every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- use `JLabel.setIcon()` as standard way, then there no reason to remove, modify and add a new `JComponents` on runtime
- in some cases there is issue with repainting `Icon` in the `JLabel` (from external sources, www sites, etc.), then you have to call,

> ```
> myIcon.getImage().flush();
> myLabel.setIcon(myIcon);
> ```

- use CardLayout with a few views, then any action is only to switch betweens cards

  ---

otherwise

- have to call `container.revalidate()` and `container.repaint()`, as last code lines, one time, after all changes are done
- for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame with JLabel contains [ImageIcon / Icon created on fly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7944388/714968)

Comment: I was trying your suggestion, and I just noticed something awkward. The  new images are there after all but right next to each other. It just added images side by side instead of replacing...

Comment: 1. then container.revalidate() and container.repaint() works in all cases, 2. final result depends od used LayoutManager for JPanel, 3. maybe use to JList, modify code example from JComboBoxand image renderer from Oracle tutorial

Comment: Yup, your answer showed the way. Apparently the panelPaintings added label components but never replaced them. **panelMain.remove(panelPainting);** was also unnecessary. Thank you.