# repaint function not work when event happen

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, background-color, thread-sleep

i am trying to change button **background** color for 10 time when **event**  happen?

---

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            Random r = new Random();
            jButton2.setBackground(new Color(r.nextInt(150), r.nextInt(150), r.nextInt(150)));
            jButton2.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(200);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

}
```

but the **button** show the last color??

---

thanks it's work correctly

```
int x = 0;
Timer timer;
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Random r = new Random();
            jButton2.setBackground(new Color(r.nextInt(150), r.nextInt(150), r.nextInt(150)));
            jButton2.repaint();
            if(x==10){
                timer.stop();
                x=0;
            } else{
                x++;
            }
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}
```

Comment: Glad you've got it working. Consider though creating your Random object only once at the beginning of your class. There's no need to keep creating it anew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call Thread.sleep(...) on the Swing event thread as this puts the entire Swing GUI to sleep. In other words, your GUI does no painting, accepts no user input or interaction at all and becomes completely useless while the event (also known as the **E**vent **D**ispatch **T**hread or **EDT**). Use a Swing Timer instead. Please check out the [Swing Timer Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more help on this.

Also have a look at some of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943584/update-jlabel-every-x-seconds-from-arraylistlist-java), including mKorbel's.